# reduce width of bars in multiple barplot R

Tags: r, plot, width, bar-chart

I need to reduce the width of the bars in the below multiple barplot:

[image]

I tried to use the `space` option as per here [Change width of bars in barchart (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750931/change-width-of-bars-in-barchart-r) but it seems that with multiple barplot (i.e. in my case 4 bars per each variable) the function `space` does not work.

Here's some fake data that reproduce the plot:

```
mat_example = matrix(rnorm(40), 4, 10)
barplot(mat_example[,c(1:10)], beside = TRUE)
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: this is certainly a duplicate, but in OPs defense, [Google](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=width+barplot+r&oq=width+barplot+r&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.5905j1j7&client=ms-unknown&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) only returns the (imo) terrible answer they referenced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `help(barplot)` there is this paragraph:

> space: the amount of space (as a fraction of the average bar width)
>             left before each bar.  May be given as a single number or one
>             number per bar.  **If ‘height’ is a matrix and ‘beside’ is
>             ‘TRUE’, ‘space’ may be specified by two numbers, where the
>             first is the space between bars in the same group, and the
>             second the space between the groups.**  If not given
>             explicitly, it defaults to ‘c(0,1)’ if ‘height’ is a matrix
>             and ‘beside’ is ‘TRUE’, and to 0.2 otherwise.

So in your case this should work:

```
barplot(table, beside=TRUE, space=c(0, 2))
```

With your example:

```
mat_example <- matrix(rnorm(40), 4, 10)
barplot(mat_example[,c(1:10)], beside=TRUE, space=c(0, 5))
```

[image]

Comment: @aaaaa Also, `barplot(mat_example, etc)` is enough, no need for the index.