# How to create a barplot in R with frequencies on the y-axis not the densities?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I want a bar plot for the following data.

```
bloodgroup <- c("O",    "A",    "A",    "O",    "O",
                "B",    "B",    "A",    "A",    "A",
                "A",    "O",    "O",    "O",    "B",
                "O",    "O",    "A",    "O",    "A",
                "A",    "O",    "AB",   "B",    "O",
                "AB",   "B",    "O",    "A",    "AB")
```

I have written the following code, but it only returns the densities. I want the frequencies on the y-axis with on each bar at the top the number of frequencies. Any idea how to this?

```
 barplot(prop.table(table(bloodgroup)))
```

Comment: `barplot(table(bloodgroup))`?

Comment: I worked, but how do I add the frequencies on top of each bar?

Comment: See [How to display the frequency at the top of each factor in a barplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12481430/1422451) and its dup reference, [add text to horizontal barplot in R, y-axis at different scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4217207/1422451). Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before you ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach using `ggplot2` and `dplyr` pipelines. You need to transform your vector to dataframe and then summarise to obtain the counts. After that the plot can be sketched using `geom_bar()` and `geom_text()` to add the desired labels. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
bloodgroup <- c("O",    "A",    "A",    "O",    "O",
                "B",    "B",    "A",    "A",    "A",
                "A",    "O",    "O",    "O",    "B",
                "O",    "O",    "A",    "O",    "A",
                "A",    "O",    "AB",   "B",    "O",
                "AB",   "B",    "O",    "A",    "AB")
#Code
bloodgroup %>% as.data.frame %>%
  rename(Var='.') %>%
  group_by(Var) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Var,y=N,fill=Var))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format(accuracy = 2))+
  geom_text(aes(label=N),vjust=-0.25,fontface='bold')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))
```

Output:

[image]

Or with `base R`:

```
#Code 2
xx <- barplot(table(bloodgroup),ylim=c(0, 14))
coords <- as.numeric(table(bloodgroup))
text(x = xx, y = coords, label = coords, cex = 0.8,pos = 3, col = "red")
```

Output:

[image]