# visualize relationship between categorical variable and frequency of other variable in one graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

how in R, should I have a histogram with a categorical variable in x-axis and
the frequency of a continuous variable on the y axis?
is this correct?

Comment: No, I don't think it is correct. You probably want a bar plot, not a histogram. Compute aggregate counts by the categorical variable and plot the result. This is probably a duplicate. In the mean time, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64392990/how-to-create-a-barplot-in-r-with-frequencies-on-the-y-axis-not-the-densities#comment113865091_64392990).

Comment: Try asking your question on `https://stats.stackexchange.com`.  Cross Validated is a question and answer site for people interested in statistics, machine learning, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways one could interpret "one graph" in the title of the question. That said, using  the `ggplot2` package, there are at least a couple of ways to render histograms with by groups on a single page of results.

First, we'll create data frame that contains a normally distributed random variable with a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 20. We also include a group variable that has one of four values, A, B, C, or D.

```
set.seed(950141237) # for reproducibility of results 
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A","B","C","D"),200),
                 y_value = rnorm(800,mean=100,sd = 20))
```

The resulting data frame has 800 rows of randomly generated values from a normal distribution, assigned into 4 groups of 200 observations.

Next, we will render this in `ggplot2::ggplot()` as a histogram, where the color of the bars is based on the value of `group`.

```
ggplot(data = df,aes(x = y_value, fill = group)) + geom_histogram()
```

...and the resulting chart looks like this:

[image]

In this style of histogram the values from each group are stacked atop each other(i.e. the frequency of group A is added to B, etc. before rendering the chart), which might not be what the original poster intended.

We can verify the "stacking" behavior by removing the `fill = group` argument from `aes()`.

```
# verify the stacking behavior
ggplot(data = df,aes(x = y_value)) + geom_histogram()
```

...and the output, which looks just like the first chart, but drawn in a single color.

[image]

Another way to render the data is to use group with `facet_wrap()`, where each distribution appears in a different facet on one chart.

```
ggplot(data = df,aes(x = y_value)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~group)
```

The resulting chart looks like this:

[image]

The facet approach makes it easier to see differences in frequency of y values between the groups.